# Do (some) vintage GE Immersible Coffeemakers contain PCBs?

Tags: coffee-machines, percolator, history

I recently acquired a brand new vintage General Electric Immersible Coffeemaker. When I opened the box, I found that the carafe is plastic.

The paperwork was printed 1974.

What are the chances the plastic pot has [PCBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychlorinated_biphenyl)? I don't want to use the pot if the plastic might contain PCBs.

Comment: Do you mean BPA instead? PCBs would be an unusual additive to a plastic coffee pot.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I meant BPA’s.